# Extracting images from multiple urls

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I would like to iterate through a list of urls and extract images from each page. However there are certain cases where an image does not exist and the url is different from the pattern of urls I typically observe.

So for example with the code I have whenever I encounter a url like this-

 I get an error message

This is the code I have written:

```
file = pd.read_csv(path)
for index,row in file.iterrows():
    site = row['link']
    response = requests.get(site)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    pics = soup.find('img')
    pic_url = pics['src']
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(pic_url,'C:\\Users\\User\\test\\pictures\\'+ str(site.split('/')[-1])+'.jpg')
```

Here is a sample of my data

```
name            link
 one            https://boxrec.com/en/proboxer/844760
 two            https://boxrec.com/en/proboxer/838706
 three          https://boxrec.com/en/proboxer/879108
 four           https://boxrec.com/en/proboxer/745266
```

This is my error message

> ValueError: unknown url type: '/build/images/main/avatar.jpeg'

UPDATE:
I tried adding try, except to capture the error and continue. However I then start getting the error message

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

I then updated my code to this

```
try:
         pic_url = pics['src']
except:
         image = 'https://chapters.theiia.org/central-mississippi/About/ChapterOfficers/_w/person-placeholder_jpg.jpg'
         urllib.request.urlretrieve(image,'C:\\Users\\User\\test\\pictures\\'+str(site.split('/')[-1])+'.jpg')
try:
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(pic_url,'C:\\Users\\User\\test\\pictures\\'+ str(site.split('/')[-1])+'.jpg')
except:
        image = 'https://chapters.theiia.org/central-mississippi/About/ChapterOfficers/_w/person-placeholder_jpg.jpg'
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(image,'C:\\Users\\User\\test\\pictures\\'+str(site.split('/')[-1])+'.jpg')
```

but this returns multiple repetitions and in certain cases blank pictures for id's where pictures actually exist

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to avoid the error and continue with other valid images you can  enclose it in `try: except: continue`

Something like this

```py
try:
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(...)
except ValueError:
    continue
```

Comment: tried this, but getting a lot of pictures being repeated multiple times

Answer (score 0):

Just simply put it in a try/except block with the for loop so with every exception it continues to the next thing on the list

```
file = pd.read_csv(path)
for index,row in file.iterrows():
    site = row['link']
    try:
       response = requests.get(site)
       soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
       pics = soup.find('img')
       pic_url = pics['src']
       urllib.request.urlretrieve(pic_url,'C:\\Users\\User\\test\\pictures\\'+ str(site.split('/')[-1])+'.jpg')
    except Exception:
            continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Because '/build/images/main/avatar.jpeg' is the relative path.It's a default avatar that can be filtered out.If you don't want to filter it out, you can convert it to full path.The following code includes the automatic conversion function.
The following code uses the library simplified_scrapy

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc 
file = pd.read_csv(path)
for index,row in file.iterrows():
    site = row['link']
    response = requests.get(site)
    doc = SimplifiedDoc(response.text)
    pics = doc.listImg(url=site)[0]
    pic_url = pics.url
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(pic_url,'C:\\Users\\User\\test\\pictures\\'+ str(site.split('/')[-1])+'.jpg')
```